# How to take items from objects in props and put them into state every time props update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass 2 objects *(edited)* as props and I want to access them like `this.state.time1` and not `this.state.timeInfo.time1` in the child component. Is that possible?

I tried `this.state = { ...props.clockInfo, ...props.gameState };` in constructor, but child's state doesn't update, when `props.gameState` changes.

EDIT:

this function changes state of parent component and props of child component, but not state of child's component.

```
  startGame = () => {
    let gameState = {
      myTurn: true,
      myColor: 0,
      gameStarted: true,
      gameEnded: false
    };
    this.setState({
      gameState: gameState
    });

    console.log(this.state);
  };
```

`<ChessClock clockInfo={this.props.clockInfo} gameState={this.state.gameState} onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)} />`

Child Component (lots of console.logs, because i tried debugging this)

````
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...props.clockInfo, ...props.gameState };
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
    console.log(props);
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row text-center w-100 GUI_clocks">
        <div className="h2 col">
          {this.state.time1 / 60 - ((this.state.time1 / 60) % 1)}:{this.state.time1 % 60 < 10 ? "0" + (this.state.time1 % 60) : this.state.time1 % 60}
        </div>
        <div className="h2 col">
          {this.state.time2 / 60 - ((this.state.time2 / 60) % 1)}:{this.state.time2 % 60 < 10 ? "0" + (this.state.time2 % 60) : this.state.time2 % 60}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    console.log("CHESS CLOCK COMPONENT WILL RECEIVE PROPS");
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(this.props);
    //this.setState(...this.props.gameState, ...this.props.clockInfo);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("CHESS CLOCK DID UPDATE");
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(undefined);
  }

  startStopClock() {
    if (this.props.myTurn && this.props.gameStarted && this.timerID == null) {
      this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.state.myPlayerNumber === 1) {
          this.setState({ time1: this.state.time1 - 1 });
        } else {
          this.setState({ time2: this.state.time2 - 1 });
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    if (!this.props.myTurn || !this.props.gameStarted) {
      if (this.timerID != null) {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
        this.timerID = null;
        console.log("cleaned interval; " + this.timerID);
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: show your parent and child component please

Comment: something like this https://codesandbox.io/embed/render-props-with-react-lq97p ?

Comment: I added more code as requested.

Comment: That example you provided me with, doesn't do what I wanted as I'm passing objects, not arrays, I said it wrong, my bad.

Comment: why would you want to do that, why don't use props directly instead of mapping to the state?

Comment: Because I'll be updating state and I can't update props without using callback to parent component, right? I don't want to do that every second. Plus I want to put every parameter into object and not have to use addititional word everytime I use state in child component, if that's possible.

Comment: but then you have sync problems like in this case, the state on the child does not updates when props updates automatically because are not linked, you definitely should use callbacks in this case, if you do not want to repeat `this.props` all the time inside your render, you could do something like this `const { clockInfo } = this.props`, then when the state on parent gets updated you would have your props updated in your child component